# Manipulate (TRUE , FALSE) values Inside an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a range that contains values `”TRUE”` and `”FALSE”` as strings (not output of a formula). 
When I manipulated the range inside an array, I noticed that the cells of values (TRUE , FALSE) did not changed. 
I already know that (TRUE , FALSE) is a reserved words, But in my case how to manipulated it?

```
Sub True_False()

   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
   Dim rng As Range, arr, lastRow As Long, i As Long, c As Long
   
   lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
   Set rng = ws.Range("A2:E" & lastRow)
   
   arr = rng.Value2

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
     For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
       arr(i, c) = LCase(CStr(arr(i, c)))
     Next c
    Next i

   rng.Value = arr
 
End Sub
```

Comment: So you expect "TRUE" to be handled as a boolean value not as a string?

Comment: I am afraid that the respective range **is not formatted as text**... Please, try `With rng` `.NumberFormat = "@"`  `.value2 = arr` `End With`.

Comment: @FaneDuru , I found that it was formatted as `General`. You are correct, changing it to text, then my issue fixed

Comment: Then, how did you know that the respective values are not `Boolean` type, as Excel automatically convert when place them in a range? The modified value in the array **is a string**, but because of the Excel way of guessing it is converted to `Boolean` **when dropped in the range**... In fact, if you need them being strings, you could use conversion (as in your code) when compare their values with something else ("true", "false"). Or convert the reference: `If arr(1,1) = CBol("true") Then`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepending the value with an apostrophe forces Excel to treat it as a string.

```
Sub True_False()

   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
   Dim rng As Range, arr, lastRow As Long, i As Long, c As Long
   
   lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
   Set rng = ws.Range("A2:E" & lastRow)
   
   arr = rng.Value2

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
     For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
       arr(i, c) = "'" & LCase(CStr(arr(i, c)))
     Next c
    Next i

   rng.Value = arr
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple numberformatting should keep it as you wanted

```
rng.NumberFormat = "@"
rng.Value = arr
```

If you'd like to add formulas in those cells later however, I'd advise you take TinMan's solution.
My pet peeve is inserting a column next to it and having to format it to General because of the text-Numberformat "@" from a previous macro (: